# Can VSTS Query filter by comparison between parent and child items?

Tags: full-text-search, azure-devops

Is there a way to do a query to compare fields from linked item to parent item?  What I need to do a query finding Items that have been changed after their parent has been changed.  In order to do this I want to do a query in which I find the relevant items and display linked items where the state change date < the change date of the parent item.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t such feature in VSTS, you may build a VSTS extension or application to do it through Work item rest API.